# Как скомпилировать .py в .apk

Tags: python, tkinter, компиляция, apk

Как приложении написанной на python tkinter скомпилировать в АПК файл?

Comment: вроде как никак на tkinter но это не точно. Лучше pyqt или kivy использовать

Comment: Никак. tkinter не предназначен для андроида